# Finding new probability density function with change of variable Y=sqrt(X)

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Say we have a given distribution, such as X~No(a, b). I am trying to find the pdf and mean for $Y=\sqrt{X}$.

I know the steps for finding the PDF, but since Y can only take on positive values, then the new PDF is only valid for Y>0.

Then how does this affect the mean, and how would I go about finding the mean?

Comment: $Y = \sqrt{X}$ is imaginary when $X < 0$.  Are you sure that the problem does not say $Y = \sqrt{|X|}$?

Answer (score 1):

If $Y=\sqrt{|X|}$, then, for every $y\gt0$,
$$
f_Y(y)=2y\cdot(f_X(y^2)+f(-y^2)).$$